# Jump from emacs .tex file to .pdf without pressing enter every time

Tags: latex, aquamacs, skim

I am on OSX 12.2 and am using Aquamacs 3.6  GNU Emacs 25.3.50.1, and I edit a .tex file manuscript.tex with Aquamacs Emacs. I press Cmd + shift + left mouse button to jump from the .tex file to the pdf, and I get asked in the lower bar

```
View command: (lambda () (aquamacs-call-viewer 156 "manuscript.tex"))
```

Then I press enter and I get correctly prompted to the PDF, which is opened with Skim (156 is the line number).

How may I avoid being asked to press enter every time, in order to jump to the pdf directly?

Comment: What is `C-S-left mouse button` bounded to ?

Comment: How do I know ?

Comment: Maybe with the describe-binding function, you can call it with "M-x describe-binding" or it's by default bounded to "C-h b". Then look for your binding in the list and its description

Comment: I don't understand anything of what you wrote.

Comment: "M-x describe-binding" means hit the "Meta" key with the key "x" on your keyboard. The meta key on Aquamacs is by default the "Option" button, see here : https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AquamacsFAQ#h5o-7

Comment: If I do so, the only line in which '<C-S-left>' appears is the following
'<C-S-kp-left> <C-S-left>'

Comment: did you tried in a configuration where your keybind make actual sense ? With the right files opened ?